# How are badges ordered on the user profile?

Tags: support, design, badges, profile-page, activity-tab

Here're my top three bronze badges on the main site, it seems they're ranked by class:

[image]

But if I go to my activity's badges section and rank them by class, the top three bronze badges are these:

[image]

Which is quite different from the ones shown on the profile page.

So, I'm wondering how are badges ordered on the user profile?

Comment: Hey, I'm just wondering, how can we display those badges like that on profiles?

Comment: @Bando The first screenshot is the default sorting on the profile page, for the second screenshot, you'll need to go ​to the activity tab and select rank by class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The badges on the profile page are ranked by the rarity of the badge, and the ones on the activity tab are ranked by the most recent badge even when sorted by class.

On your profile page, the [proofreader badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/73/proofreader) is at the top because it is your rarest badge (Awarded 19988 times). [Tag editor badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/58/tag-editor) is your second-rarest badge (Awarded 25669 times).

And the badges on the activity tab are arranged from your most recent badge to your oldest badge because sorting them by class will only sort the type of badge (gold silver bronze) but badges with the same type will be sorted by date. (One exception is: Badges that are awarded multiple times like custodian always come to the bottom).

Comment: It's a bit weird to see rare bronze tag badges show up in my profile (https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes?tab=profile) when I also have the silver and even gold versions of them. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/10242/micro-optimization. (The 3 gold and silver badges it did pick are different one where I'm the only SO user with them, but several other users have the silver or bronze versions of some of them, e.g. [avx2] and [cpu-architecture]. Although most of my [micro-optimization] answers are on questions where I added that tag, unlike cpu-architecture :P)

Comment: @PeterCordes Well it still picks the rarest three out of your bronze badges, regardless what badges you have in the other classes.